# VS2008 reporting IFF is failing on a simple condition

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, report

I have a simple report in VS2008. I have a table which is like this:

[image]

I get the results as this:

[image]

I have already wasted 2 hours sitting in front of this issue. Moreover, my colleague didn't see any mistake in this either. I am 100% certain I have no formatting on the table. The results in the field *value* come as a string.

What wrong am I doing in the last column's code?

P.S. I have also tried

```
=IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!value.Value), Fields!value.Value, Fields!value.Value)
```

but then the data in the third column is showed as in the first one.
It seems that for some weird reason IIF is trying to parse both True and False parts and failing CDbl() on a string, but I cannot believe this can be possible, because I haven't seen a programming language doing something like this before.

Comment: "I cannot believe this can be possible, because I haven't seen a programming language doing something like this before." - if you observe that `IIF` is a **function**, not a statement, does that help understand what you're seeing? Because it's a function, it evaluates all its arguments...

Comment: @AakashM Oh god... Now that you say this... Is there any possible way to fix this problem?

Comment: Use a normal If?

IF IsNumeric(Fields!value.Value)=True then
Fields!value.Value
Else
Fields!value.Value
End If

Comment: @ChristianSauer It says IF an `Unrecognized Identifier` :(

Comment: What you can do about it depends on what reporting engine you're using - if you edit that into the question (with an appropriate tag) you might get people who know it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the comments on my post, I came up with a solution by writing these two functions. These two were both used to display data and overcome the stupidity of uneditable total field.

```
Public Function cdblf(ByVal s As Object) As Object
    If (IsNumeric(s)) Then
        Return CDbl(s)
    Else : Return Nothing
    End If
End Function

Public Function cdbls(ByVal n As Object, ByVal s As Object, ByVal b As Boolean) As Object
    If (IsNumeric(n)) Then
        Return CDbl(n)
    Else : 
        If(Not IsNothing(s)) Then
            If(b) Then
                Return CStr(Left(CStr(s), Len(CStr(s)) - 1))
            Else : Return Nothing
            End If
        Else : Return Nothing
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

The usage of these functions combined should be like this:

```
=Code.cdbls(
    Sum(Code.cdblf(Fields!value.Value)), 
    Fields!value.Value, 
    InScope("matrix1_row_name") and InScope("matrix1_column_name"))
```

This both solved the fact that I didn't want to sum string values and also there was no need to use IIF anymore.